When does the animated Disney film "Mulan" take place?
When does the animated Disney film Mulan (1998) take place?
It is made clear in the film that it takes place in China, but the time period is a lot less clear, as the film has elements of several different Chinese dynasties (the fashion is from the Tang dynasty, the Huns only ever attacked China during the Han dynasty, the Forbidden City was built in the Ming dynasty, the original folk tale was set in the Wei dynasty, etc.).

The time period is going to depend on which parts of the story you want to determine are "actual" and which are "anachronisms".
The character and general story are based on the The Ballad of Mulan which is during the Northern Wei Dynasty which was 386-584. This includes the Huns as the antagonists.
The location settings, particular the Forbidden City which was completed in 1420.
However, this is contradicted again when in Mulan II the new antagonists are the Mongols, who invaded China from 1205 to 1279.
In general the story borrows from many cultural legacies from Chinese folklore and history, and therefore cannot have an exact date prescribed to its setting.

The original story of Hua Mulan usually happens during the Northern Wei Dynasty, about AD 399 to 535.

The historical setting of the Ballad of Mulan is usually the Northern Wei's military campaigns against the nomadic Rouran. A later adaptation has Mulan active around the founding of the Tang dynasty (c. 620 CE).1

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hua_Mulan
in the movie Mulan (1998):

The Huns, led by the ruthless Shan Yu, invade China by breaching the Great Wall. The Emperor orders a general mobilization, with conscription notices requiring one man from each family to join the Imperial Army.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulan_(1998_film)
In history, the Huns are only known for living and fighting in western Asia and Europe.

Considering the setting and their point of origin, Shan Yu and his Huns could, in fact, be members of the Xiongnu people, Turco-Mongol tribes who lived in the lands north of the Great Wall and conquered much of the Central Asia steppe in the 3rd-1st centuries BC. It is thought by many that the Huns that invaded Europe around 375 AD are descendants of those Western Xiongnu who were evicted by the Chinese in Turkmenistan. This is further supported by Shan-Yu's name, as a "Shanyu" or "Chanyu" was what the Xiongnu leaders were called, much like a Mongol leader would be "Khan."

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120762/trivia/?ref_=tt_trv_trv

The Huns could not have been the enemy of Mulan and her allies. The Huns were pretty much done by 469 CE and spent their time attacking the western and eastern empires of Rome, not the Chinese. The invasion of China that Mulan is alleged to have helped fight occurred in 600 CE. The Gokturks were the likely opponent that Mulan would have faced.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120762/goofs/?tab=gf&ref_=tt_trv_gf

The Xiongnu (Chinese: 匈奴; pinyin: Xiōngnú,[12] [ɕjʊ́ŋ.nǔ]) were a tribal confederation[13] of nomadic peoples who, according to ancient Chinese sources, inhabited the eastern Eurasian Steppe from the 3rd century BC to the late 1st century AD. Modu Chanyu, the supreme leader after 209 BC, founded the Xiongnu Empire.[14]


The Xiongnu split into northern and Southern factins in AD 48.  The northern Xiongnu were driven west in AD 155. The southern Xiongnu gradually became controle more and more by the Chinese government.  During the Sixteeen Kingdoms era (304-439) a few minor Chinese kingdoms were ruled by Xiongnu nobles.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiongnu
So Xiongnu were not an active barbarian military threat by the time of the Northern Wei Dynasty of 399 to 535.

The Huns were a nomadic people who lived in Central Asia, the Caucasus, and Eastern Europe between the 4th and 6th centuries AD. According to European tradition, they were first reported living east of the Volga River, in an area that was part of Scythia at the time. By 370 AD, the Huns had arrived on the Volga, causing the westwards movement of Goths and Alans. By 430, they had established a vast, but short-lived, empire on the Danubian frontier of the Roman empire in Europe.


After the death of Attila in 453, the Huns ceased to be a major threat to Rome and lost much of their empire following the Battle of Nedao (c. 454). Descendants of the Huns, or successors with similar names, are recorded by neighboring populations to the south, east, and west as having occupied parts of Eastern Europe and Central Asia from about the 4th to 6th centuries. Variants of the Hun name are recorded in the Caucasus until the early 8th century.
In the 18th century, French scholar Joseph de Guignes became the first to propose a link between the Huns and the Xiongnu people, who lived in northern China from the 3rd century BC to the late 1st century AD.3 Since Guignes's time, considerable scholarly effort has been devoted to investigating such a connection. The issue remains controversial, but recent archaeogenetic studies show some Hun-era individuals to have DNA similar to populations in ancient Mongolia. Their relationships with other entities, such as the Iranian Huns and the Huna people of South Asia, have also been disputed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huns
An old book I read long ago claimed that Attila the Hun ruled the largest empire ever, from the borders of France to the borders of China, which seems highly exaggerated compared to other sources. In any case, no historian has found any mention of "Huns" or groups with similar names invading China in the time of the Northern Wei Dynasty, circa 390 to 535.
If Mulan happened sometime during the Han Dynasty of 22 BC to 220 AD, there would have been a number of wars with the Xiongnu, who were possibly the ancestors of the Huns, and so if the movie happens in the Han Dynasty, it would not be totally silly to call the Xiongnu by the more familiar name of Huns.
The original Ballad of Mulan was set during wars between the Northern Wei Dynasty and the nomadic Rouran.

The Rouran Khaganate (柔然; Róurán), also known as Ruanruan or Juan-juan (蠕蠕; Ruǎnruǎn) (or variously Jou-jan, Ruruan, Ju-juan, Ruru, Ruirui, Rouru, Rouruan or Tantan) was a tribal confederation and later state founded by a people of Proto-Mongolic Donghu origin.[8][9] The Rouran supreme rulers used the title of "khagan", a popular title borrowed from the Xianbei.[10] The Rouran Khaganate lasted from the late 4th century until the middle 6th century, when they were defeated by a Göktürk rebellion at the peak of their power, which subsequently led to the rise of the Turks in world history.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouran_Khaganate
The Rouran Khaganate lasted from 330 to 555.  The Rouran invaded Northern Wei in 424, and there were other wars, usually Wei attacks on the Rouran, in 429, 443, 449, 453, 456, 458, 490, etc.   So the most likely date for the events in the Ballad of Mulan would be about 424, since that is a time when the Rouran invaded Northern Wei.
The Northern Wei emperor Mingyuan died in 423 aged about 31.  His son Emperor Taiwu died in 452 age 44 and was about 16 in 424.  Only one of the following emperors of the dynasty lived to be in his forties.
So if Mulan (1998) happens in the Norther Wei Dynasty, it seems very strange that the emperor is depicted as white haired and white bearded.
It is also suggested that the Gokturks could ahve been the invaders, if the story of Mulan happens about the time of the fall of the Sui Dynasty and rise of the Tang Dynasty.

The Göktürks reached their peak in the late 6th century and began to invade the Sui dynasty of China. However, the war ended due to the division of Turkic nobles and their civil war for the throne of Khagan. With the support of Emperor Wen of Sui, Yami Qaghan won the competition. However, the Göktürk empire was divided to Eastern and Western empires. Weakened by the civil war, Yami Qaghan declared allegiance to the Sui dynasty.[52] When Sui began to decline, Shibi Khagan began to assault its territory and even surrounded Emperor Yang of Sui in Siege of Yanmen (615 AD) with 100,000 cavalry troops. After the collapse of the Sui dynasty, the Göktürks intervened in the ensuing Chinese civil wars, providing support to the northeastern rebel Liu Heita against the rising Tang in 622 and 623. Liu enjoyed a long string of success but was finally routed by Li Shimin and other Tang generals and executed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6kt%C3%BCrks
The Sui Emperor Yangdi lived to be about 49 years old, while two of his grandson were made puppet emperors by rebels aged about 12 to 14. Li Yuan, Emperor Gaozu of Tang, reigned from 618 to 626 aged 52 to 60.
In the live action Mulan (2020) the enemy is Rouran.

To the north, an imperial outpost is invaded by Rouran warriors, under the leadership of Böri Khan. They are assisted by the witch Xianniang, who uses her magic to pose as a surviving soldier and report the attack to the Emperor of China; he then issues a conscription decree ordering every family to contribute one man to fight Khan's forces.
Xianniang uses her magic to take the image of the Imperial Chancellor, and persuades the Emperor to accept Böri Khan's challenge to single combat, while removing the city guards from their posts.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulan_(2020_film)
For an emperor to accept a challenge to a duel, they would have to be rather different from the usual civilian Chinese Emperor.
The emperors of the Northern Wei Dynasty were of barbarian Xianabi origin and were more likely to be warriors than most Chinese emperors, up until the reforms of Dowager Empress Feng in 484–485.
Li Yuan, emperor Gaozu of Tang, was a Sui Dynasty official and officer before he rebelled against the Sui. Thus, he may have had more fighting skills than the typical Emperor.
In Mulan (2020), the emperor, a skilled warrior, is played by Jet Li (b. 1963), who was about 55 to 56 when his scenes were filmed. That would make emperor Gaozu of Tang possibly the most likely candidate for emperor, but the film says the Rouran were the enemies, indicating the date was about 150 years before his reign.
So the two Mulan movies don’t seem to be set in specific eras but more like generic ancient or medieval China.

Okay….Well, I was only talking about the animated film, not the original tale or the live-action film. I also wanted a more clear answer. But if this is the best answer you can produce, that is fine.

Jeez, Aariz, he gave you an incredible thorough, detailed, and well-researched answer.  Don’t be petulant — unless I am missing the sarcasm...

The climax of the animated version takes place at the Forbidden City.  Construction started on that palace complex in 1406 — almost a millennium after anyone who could plausibly called a Hun would be any threat.
Do the bad guys ever refer to themselves as Huns?  Perhaps word could just be used as a slang word for “invader”, something that was very common as late as World War One.

@Michael Lorton   Empeors had been building vast palace complexs for over a thousand years before the Forbidden City was built.  There is no reason to call the palace the Forbidden City if it merely looks like it.  Would it even be possible to see Bejing from the border mountains?  Unless the palace is called the Forbidden City in dialog there is noreason  to think it was supposed to be the Forbidden City.  And if they do call it that in the  film, that makes it even more impossible to date Mulan (1998) in real history.

@ Michael Lorton  Did Chinese call enemies Huns in WWI?  Europeans may have called the Germans "Huns" In WWI because of Kaiser Wilhelm II's "Hun Speech" on 27 July 1900. though the nickname was used earlier.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hun_speech#:~:text=The%20Hun%20speech%20was%20delivered,to%20quell%20the%20Boxer%20Rebellion.

@MichaelLorton Oh, I’m sorry if I sounded petulant. I wasn’t trying to. Also, M. A. Golding, they never directly call it the Forbidden City in the film. If we can assume that it is just a random Chinese palace, then we could assume that the film takes place during the Xiongnu invasion of the Han Dynasty.

@Aariz Khan  Of course like I said the original story is supposed to happen durin the NOrthern Wei vs the Rouran or sometimes Sui/Tng vs the Gokturks.  And there is gunpowder fireworks in the climax.   https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnachronismStew

@M.A.Golding Yeah, I did know about the fireworks….Really, in the end, the film is an anachronism stew, so the closest we can get to a definitive time period would be a time period in which a group of Hun-like invaders attacked China, like the Xiongnu in the Han Dynasty. Then again, it could be set in an alternate timeline in which the actual Huns invaded China before they started attacking Europe, placing it sometime around the early 4th century in the Jin Dynasty. We will never know.
